# VS Code - Cucumber - navigate clicking the feature command to step definition

Tags: visual-studio-code, cucumber, cypress

In VS Code I have installed the Full Cucumber support plugin, but I am not able to jump to step definition from the feature file, clicking on the feature command.

All my feature files are in subfolders in:

```
cypress/integration/features/folderName1/feature1.feature
cypress/integration/features/folderName2/feature2.feature
```

etc.

All my step definition files are in:

```
cypress/support/step_definitions/folderName1/stepdef1.js
cypress/support/step_definitions/folderName2/stepdef2.js
```

etc.

In settings.json I have this:

```
 "cucumberautocomplete.steps": [
        "cypress/support/step_definitions/**/*.js"
    ],
    "cucumberautocomplete.syncfeatures": "cypress/integration/features/**/*.feature",
    "cucumberautocomplete.strictGherkinCompletion": true
```

but it is not working for any steps in feature files, saying for example : Was unable to find step for "When    I Click on link"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I've found the problem. I had a workspace with 2 projects created in VS Code. The extension works only if the cypress project is in first place in the workspace.

So I changed the order of the projects in my workspace and now clicking on the feature command jumps to step definition!